Analysing several columns of a dataset at the same time
I work with a real large dataset, where it is very difficult to look at all columns individually.
At this time I only want to count the frequency of the information provided.
Lets say I have a dataframe which looks like this:
|ID |Symptome1|Symptome2|Symptome3 |Symptome4|
|123|Rash     |Vomiting |Cough     |Pain|
|345|Urticaria|Rash     |Angioedema|Pain|

The symptoms occur at different time intervals, so I want to calculate the number of symptoms at each time interval. Symptome1 is time interval 1, Symptome2 at time interval 2, etc.
Now I want to count all Symptome1, all Samyptome2, all Symptome3 etc. separately.
In a small dataset I would probably use
dataset%>%count(Symptome1)

Of course I could do it for all columns separately, but I guess I need something like a loop?

In base R you can use lapply and make a table out of each column. This will store each column in a list:
lapply(dat[-1], table)

# Note if you have additional columns and only want the ones that have "Symptome" (sic), you can use:
lapply(dat[grep("Symptome", names(dat))], table)

If you want them in a flat format, you can use sapply and use labels = unique(unlist(dat[-1])) to ensure you've covered all the possible symptoms in the overall dataset:
sapply(dat[-1], function(x) 
  table(factor(x, levels = unique(unlist(dat[-1]))))
)

Output:
#            Symptome1 Symptome2 Symptome3 Symptome4
# Rash               1         1         0         0
# Urticaria          1         0         0         0
# Vomiting           0         1         0         0
# Cough              0         0         1         0
# Angioedema         0         0         1         0
# Pain               0         0         0         2

Data:
# using data from SamR's answer (thanks @SamR!)
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 345L), Symptome1 = c("Rash", "Urticaria"
), Symptome2 = c("Vomiting", "Rash"), Symptome3 = c("Cough", 
                                                    "Angioedema"), Symptome4 = c("Pain", "Pain")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

Per your comment, if you want to make a barplot:
xx <- sapply(dat[-1], function(x) 
  table(factor(x, levels = unique(unlist(dat[-1]))))
)

barplot(xx, beside = TRUE,
        legend.text = TRUE,
        args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty = "n"))



Happy to help - does the edit get what you want?

Could you edit your question to include sample data that more closely resembles your real data? I’ll be happy to update my answer! You could also try replacing dat[1] with dat[grep("Symptome", names(dat))] in the sapply approach

I think easier to do this by putting the data in long form first using tidyr::pivot_longer().
dat |>
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "Symptome") |>
    count(Symptome, value)

# # A tibble: 7 × 3
#   Symptome  value          n
#   <chr>     <chr>      <int>
# 1 Symptome1 Rash           1
# 2 Symptome1 Urticaria      1
# 3 Symptome2 Rash           1
# 4 Symptome2 Vomiting       1
# 5 Symptome3 Angioedema     1
# 6 Symptome3 Cough          1
# 7 Symptome4 Pain           2

Data
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 345L), Symptome1 = c("Rash", "Urticaria"
), Symptome2 = c("Vomiting", "Rash"), Symptome3 = c("Cough", 
"Angioedema"), Symptome4 = c("Pain", "Pain")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


In my dataset, I does not work out, but the result is almost what I want to do. When I use the function as you did it, I get the answer "cols you must select at least one column". I think something went wrong, because it was not recognized that with the expression used, the columns were not identified. Maybe it is because my dataset has also other columns which do not start with the expression "Symptome"? I guess the first expression as you wrote it is to select all columns which start with "Symptome"?

@USER12345 I don't know why you'd get that particular error. The use of "Symptom" in the first line just names the column Symptom rather than the default, which is name. If you want to select columns that start with "Symptom" you could replace that line with tidyr::pivot_longer(starts_with("Symptome")), or some other statement which includes the columns you wish to count and excludes the others.

We have stack(). With table():
> table(stack(dat[-1]))
            ind
values       Symptome1 Symptome2 Symptome3 Symptome4
  Angioedema         0         0         1         0
  Cough              0         0         1         0
  Pain               0         0         0         2
  Rash               1         1         0         0
  Urticaria          1         0         0         0
  Vomiting           0         1         0         0

Or aggregate():
> X = stack(dat[-1])
> X$n = seq(nrow(X))
> aggregate(n ~ ., X, FUN = length)
      values       ind n
1       Rash Symptome1 1
2  Urticaria Symptome1 1
3       Rash Symptome2 1
4   Vomiting Symptome2 1
5 Angioedema Symptome3 1
6      Cough Symptome3 1
7       Pain Symptome4 2

dat is stolen from SamR's answer.

Thanks for your recommendation. Stack works out, too.

Here is another way of presenting the results
table(
  reshape(
    dat,
    idvar = "ID",
    varying = -1,
    direction = "long",
    v.names = "Symptome",
    timevar = "SymptomeID"
  )
) 

which gives a high-dimensional array without missing any information
, , Symptome = Angioedema

     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 0 0 0
  345 0 0 1 0

, , Symptome = Cough

     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 0 1 0
  345 0 0 0 0

, , Symptome = Pain

     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 0 0 1
  345 0 0 0 1

, , Symptome = Rash

     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 1 0 0 0
  345 0 1 0 0

, , Symptome = Urticaria

     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 0 0 0
  345 1 0 0 0

, , Symptome = Vomiting

     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 1 0 0
  345 0 0 0 0


On top of the above high-dimensional format, you can slice the array from an interest aspect, e.g., Symptome
table(
  reshape(
    dat,
    idvar = "ID",
    varying = -1,
    direction = "long",
    v.names = "Symptome",
    timevar = "SymptomeID"
  )
) %>% asplit("Symptome")

and then you will obtain a list
$Angioedema
     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 0 0 0
  345 0 0 1 0

$Cough
     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 0 1 0
  345 0 0 0 0

$Pain
     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 0 0 1
  345 0 0 0 1

$Rash
     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 1 0 0 0
  345 0 1 0 0

$Urticaria
     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 0 0 0
  345 1 0 0 0

$Vomiting
     SymptomeID
ID    1 2 3 4
  123 0 1 0 0
  345 0 0 0 0

